# Upload app using old version of Xcode. Will the app be available on iOS 10 devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't want to update to `Xcode 8` after hearing that people got problems with`cocoa pods`. I know that I have to eventually, but what I wonder is if I can upload an app to the App store using `Xcode 7` and `Swift 2.3` and still have it available for `iOS 10` users?

Comment: do you want to shutdown for iOS `10 user ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fortunately Yes**

It will be applicable for all devices. Because you set Minimum Target, Not maximum.

So it will be run above the version, you set  as target.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can upload your application using Xcode 7.x (or below) and it will be available for iOS 10 users.

[image]

The Deployment Target is the determinant (minimum)